# Python execute a request with multiple URLs from a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I'm new to python.

I've made a list with URLs and I want to do `urllib.request` for all the URLs inside the list. My list currently has 5 URLs however I can only request one index at a time `urlib.Request(List[0])` and if I do `urlib.Request(List[0:4])` I'm getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Farzad/Desktop/Python/Webscraping/Responseheaderinfo.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = urllib.urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Users\Farzad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Farzad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Farzad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Farzad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Farzad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1387, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ['http>
```

---

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
import OpenSSL


List = open("C:\\Users\\Farzad\\Desktop\\hosts.txt").read().splitlines()

length = len(List)
for i in range(length): 
    print(List) 

request = urllib.Request(List[0])
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36')
response = urllib.urlopen(request)
rdata = response.info()
ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(request.origin_req_host)
```

Comment: you can do a for loop over urls and execute the request one by one. what is your question?

Comment: How would an example be?

Comment: looping with for

Comment: Just like one lane of road is not for more than one vehicle side by side. `class Request:

    def __init__(self, url, data=None, headers={},
                 origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False,
                 method=None):` The url takes one, not a list

Comment: I've tried `for lurl in List:` and `request = urllib.Request(lurl)` however it only executes the first URL in the List

Comment: @caot Is there any way I can work around that and do one url at a time?

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @wwii I've done a for statement already but it does not give the output I want.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be as the follows:

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import logging
from celery.app.log import Logging

List = open("C:\\Users\\Farzad\\Desktop\\hosts.txt").read().splitlines()

length = len(List)
for url in List:
    print(url)

    try:
        request = urllib.Request(url)
        request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36')
        response = urllib.urlopen(request)
        rdata = response.info()
        ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(request.origin_req_host)
    except Exception as e:
        print(logging.traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: I've done that however it only requests 1 url and not each url in the list.

Comment: add a sample hosts.txt, and state what's your expected output

Comment: It's just 5 different URLs in http:// format each on their own line. I'm saving the data in my local sql database and with your suggested code it only saves data from 1 of the URLs and not all of them. I want it to INSERT the data for all the URLs provided inside the hosts.txt file.

Comment: @fazzerking put a `try ... except` around the code. Based on the error your posted, the url might not be valid, so you can try the `url` in a browser to see what happens.